# Angular: Load SVG from path and stringify it

Tags: string, angular, svg

I need to load an svg file from the assets folder and stringify the content. Can't find any solution int the web but here is my approach.

```
    let svg = await this.httpClient.get(`assets/images/result/${this.icon}.svg`)
.pipe(
      map(res => {
        const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        const svgString = serializer.serializeToString(<any>res);
      })
    ).toPromise();
```

Answer (score 9):

i figured it out.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Accept', 'image/svg+xml');
const svgString =
  await this.httpClient.get(`assets/images/result/${this.icon}.svg`, {headers, responseType: 'text'}).toPromise();
```

important is that you define the header with accept "image/svg+xml" and 
 as responseType "text